# How to remove the grey background noise

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, background-removal

I'm doing some exercises with photoshop. I wish to transform a design to only black and white draw without background.

I'm working on this image
[image]

I tried two ways:
[image]

[image]

but it always remain a grey background noise inside the character.
Is there a way to remove it in a quick way?

Comment: Many would redraw the key line if that was the goal. Filters and/or adjustments will often only take someone so far.